# Flash security pop up (how to get it?)

Tags: security, flash, popup, actionscript

I wrote a flash script that is embedded into an HTML page. The flash script (AS3), needs access to the users microphone and camera. I've seen on other websites when they want to use my camera/ microphone flash automatically pops up a box asking the user to permit.

In my case, even though in my global settings for my webpage it says "always ask" under permissions, flash doesn't ask me anything and just blocks the script from accessing the microphone. The script loads fine, just doesn't prompt for access and the user has to manually right click, and go to settings and put setting to "allow".

Searching for this topic on Google is rather difficult as there is too much irrelevant stuff with the same keywords. Thanks for your time.

Edit: This is how I embed just in case I'm not doing it right.

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0" width="200" height="20" id="myflash" align="middle">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
<param name="movie" value="/baseDir/myflash.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
<param name=base VALUE="/baseDir/">
<embed src="/baseDir/myflash.swf" base="/baseDir/" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="200" height="20" name="myflash" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="always" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by making your SWF's dimensions larger. Your embedded SWF must be at least so big for the security dialog to show up:

> **Important:** Flash Player displays a
>   Privacy dialog box that lets the user
>   choose whether to allow or deny access
>   to the camera. **Make sure your
>   application window size is at least
>   215 x 138 pixels**; this is the minimum
>   size required to display the dialog
>   box.

via [livedocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html)

Comment: Mr Tim Cooper, you saved me a lot of time and trouble. Thank you, it works :)

Answer (score 1):

- is your swf at least 215 x 138 in size (minimum size to display the privacy box)?
- is it an air app (in which case it doesn't show up)?
- have you already given this permission? (i don't know if flash holds the previous choice or not - try clearing out your local shared objects and try again)
- are you running this locally (in which case, if your folder is set to be always trusted - http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html, it won't ask)

Comment: thanks divillysausages your first suggestion is the correct one, but sorry Tim cooper above you posted the correct answer. Thank you for your time.